# Does $z^4+2z^2+z=0$ have complex roots?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Does $z^4+2z^2+z=0$ have complex roots? How to find them? Besides $z=0$, I got the equation $re^{3i\theta}+2re^{i\theta}=e^{i(\pi+2k\pi)}$, $k\in \mathbb Z$. How to find the complex roots?

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of algebra, every polynomial of degree $n$ has exactly $n$ roots in $\mathbb{C}$. As for finding yours, though, I'm not sure.

Comment: The polynomial is $zP$ where $P = z^3+2z+1$. Since $\frac{dP}{dz} = 3z^2 + 2$ is positive for all $z$, it follows that $P$ is an increasing function and can have only one real root.

Comment: Theophile's answer is by far the best here. Note we can get even more via a quick application of Rouche's Theorem, which tells us each root must be the disk $|z| \le 2$ (since on the circle of radius two, $|2z^2 + z| \le 2|z|^2 + |z| = 10 and $|z^4| = 16,$ we conclude all four roots lie in the disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enough to check the discriminant for $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$:
$$
\Delta_3=-27 a^2 d^2+18 a b c d-4 a c^3-4 b^3 d+b^2 c^2
$$
$$
\Delta_3=\begin{cases} >0 & \text{3 distinct real roots}\\
<0 & \text{1 real, 2 conjugate complex roots}\\
=0 & \text{3 real roots with duplicates}\\
\end{cases}
$$
In your case, it's $a=1$, $b=0$, $c=2$ and $d=1$, so $\Delta_3=-59$, hence the equation has one real and two complex conjugate roots, with all 3 distinct. As for finding the roots themselves, the Cardano formula helps [check this out](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_Formula). The final result is:
$$
x_1=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{177}-9\right)}}{3^{2/3}}-2 \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3
   \left(\sqrt{177}-9\right)}}
$$
$$
x_2=\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)
   \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3 \left(\sqrt{177}-9\right)}}-\frac{\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right)
   \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{177}-9\right)}}{2\ 3^{2/3}}
$$
$$
x_3=\left(1-i
   \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3 \left(\sqrt{177}-9\right)}}-\frac{\left(1+i
   \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{177}-9\right)}}{2\
   3^{2/3}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

According to Wolfy,
the roots are
$0, ≈-0.453397651516404,
≈0.22669882575820 \pm 1.46771150871022 i
$
so the answer is yes.

Another way to see this is that,
if 
$f(z) = z^4+2z^2+z$,
then
$f'(z)
= 4z^3+4z+1
$
and
$f''(z)
= 12z^2+4
\gt 0
$
so $f(z)$
can have at most two real roots.

Since
$f(0) = 0$
and $f'(0)=1 \ne 0$,
$f(z)$ has exactly
two real roots
so has
two (conjugate) complex roots
since all its coefficients
are real.

Comment: I think OP is asking for complex, not real roots.

Comment: I showed that it has two real and two complex roots. This exactly answers the question. Did you not read my last sentence?

Comment: The question asks, "Does $z^2+2z^2+z=0$ have complex roots? [...] How to find the complex roots?" Your answer addresses only the first part and the rest is done with Wolfy.